# Wordpress Plugins - MultiPage Architecture

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm a long-time web developer, but a wordpress newbie :) and trying to reason about WP architecture for multipage plugins.

For a project of mine I wish to create a wordpress plugin, which runs on multiple number of pages, each with a different view, based on the specific route.

for example, my project is a remote-events app, with different views in every step of the event registration process - events catalog; event page (with more details); event registration; checkout and payment.

I don't expect my users to create multiple pages, embed different shortcodes per views and wire the proper routes. A single-click plugin installation should do it for them.

does anyone has experience or know of an example of this kind of plugin model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The catalog and single page are the natural pages created for each new post type.
https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types
If you create a new post type, let's say "Events", you can get a new archive page that shows the list of Event posts and you will be able to have inner views for all the events. It is possible to create default templates for this type of page:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types

For other pages, I think that you can do the same way as Woocommerce did - they have the shortcodes placed on the specific page like Checkout or shopping Cart, but those pages are auto-created.
This will allow users to wrap your Checkout content with some CTAs, banners, or other content without touching the actual template - some flexibility with Single-click installation.